# How to convert Any to Int in Swift

Tags: swift

I get an error when declaring i

```
var users =  Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>()
users.append(["Name":"user1","Age":20])
var i:Int = Int(users[0]["Age"])
```

How to get the int value?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`var i = users[0]["Age"] as Int`

As GoZoner points out, if you don't know that the downcast will succeed, use:

`var i = users[0]["Age"] as? Int`

The result will be `nil` if it fails

Comment: sometimes it returns nil. I used this method to parse from `WKBridge`

Answer (score 27):

Swift 4 answer :

```
if let str = users[0]["Age"] as? String, let i = Int(str) {
  // do what you want with i
}
```

Comment: I have encountered the issue by unwrapping content which looked like Optional(3).  I tried to cast it as? Int then as? String - both failed. Then tried to unwrap and use the type which caused the exception which revealed that Swift decided to use Int8 for this value. 

So folk, Int8 is not convertable to Int, thinking Swift engineers.  

Ended up checking all int types in if/else flow.

Answer (score 13):

If you are sure the result is an `Int` then use:

```
var i = users[0]["Age"] as! Int
```

but if you are unsure and want a `nil` value if it is not an `Int` then use:

```
var i = users[0]["Age"] as? Int
```

> “Use the optional form of the type cast operator (as?) when you are
>   not sure if the downcast will succeed. This form of the operator will
>   always return an optional value, and the value will be nil if the
>   downcast was not possible. This enables you to check for a successful
>   downcast.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: It's worth noting that the type of `i` in the first example is `Int` but the type of `i` in the second example will be `Int?`.

Comment: Right.  I think Apple might think of `as Int` and `as Int?` instead of introducing `as?`

Comment: That's a good point actually. I suppose `as?` is equivalent to `-isKindOfClass:`, but moving the `?` would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

This may have worked previously, but it's not the answer for Swift 3.  Just to clarify, I don't have the answer for Swift 3, below is my testing using the above answer, and clearly it doesn't work.

My data comes from an NSDictionary

```
print("subvalue[multi] = \(subvalue["multi"]!)")
print("as Int = \(subvalue["multi"]! as? Int)")
if let multiString = subvalue["multi"] as? String {
  print("as String = \(multiString)")
  print("as Int = \(Int(multiString)!)")
}
```

The output generated is:

```
subvalue[multi] = 1
as Int = nil
```

Just to spell it out:
a) The original value is of type Any? and the value is: 1
b) Casting to Int results in nil
c) Casting to String results in nil (the print lines never execute)

**EDIT**
The answer is to use NSNumber
let num = subvalue["multi"] as? NSNumber

Then we can convert the number to an integer
let myint = num.intValue

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're using `NSDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`?  `as? Int` should work in fine in Swift 3.

Comment: Actually, yeah, that's definitely the problem.  `NSDictionary` values are `AnyObject`, which can't cast to `Int` because it's not an object type.  Use a Swift dictionary instead and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let id = json["productID"] as? String {
   self.productID = Int32(id, radix: 10)!
}
```

This worked for me. `json["productID"]` is of type `Any`. 
If it can be cast to a string, then convert it to an Integer.