# How to convert Any to Int in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string

Before asking this question I have searched the Stackoverflow's related questions, and found a similar one: [How to convert Any to Int in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091989/how-to-convert-any-to-int-in-swift).

My requirement is not that less:

```
let tResult = result as? [String:AnyObject]
let stateCode = tResult?["result"] as? Int
```

My need is if the `tResult?["result"]` is a `String` class, I want it to be convert to `Int` too, rather than to `nil`.

In `objective-c`, I wrote a `class method` to get the converted `Int`:

```
+ (NSInteger)getIntegerFromIdValue:(id)value
{
    NSString *strValue;
    NSInteger ret = 0;
    if(value != nil){
        strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value];
        if(![strValue isEqualToString:@""] && ![strValue isEqualToString:@"null"]){
            ret = [strValue intValue];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Is it possible to write a similar `class method` using Swift3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Less verbose answer:

```
let key = "result"
let stateCode = tResult?[key] as? Int ?? Int(tResult?[key] as? String ?? "")
```

Results:

```
let tResult: [String: Any]? = ["result": 123] // stateCode: 123
let tResult: [String: Any]? = ["result": "123"] // stateCode: 123
let tResult: [String: Any]? = ["result": "abc"] // stateCode: nil
```

Comment: Not sure if the compiler will compile that line fast

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti indeed, I didn't test the performance. I hope the compiler is smart enough to compile the line fast enough :)

Answer (score 3):

```
if let stateCode = tResult["result"] as? String {
    if let stateCodeInt = Int(stateCode){
        // stateCodeInt is Int
    }
}else if let stateCodeInt = tResult["result"] as? Int {
    // stateCodeInt is Int
}
```

Something like this should work

Answer (score 3):

```
if 
    let tResult = result as? [String:AnyObject],
    let stateCodeString = tResult["result"] as? String,
    let stateCode = Int(stateCodeString)
{
    // do something with your stateCode
}
```

And you don't need any own `class methods`.

Comment: This Principe works for me to read  NSNumber  from plist as Any and convert to string and next to Int. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
class func getIntegerFromIdValue(_ value: Any) -> Int {
    var strValue: String
    var ret = 0
    if value != nil {
        strValue = "\(value)"
        if !(strValue == "") && !(strValue == "null") {
            ret = Int((strValue as NSString ?? "0").intValue)
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```