# Count occurrences of a value

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the count of value from a `key,value` pairs of a `[String: Any]` dictionary

```
for item in mainData {
var answerDict = [String: Any]()
var totalCountValOne = 0

for (key,value) in item.extraAnswers {
   if key.contains("correct") {
      answerDict[key] = value
   }
}
for (key,value) in answerDict {
   let lastChar = key.last
    answerFinalDict[Int(lastChar?.description ?? "") ?? 0] = "\(value)"
    print("value \(value)")
                        
    for (key, value) in answerDict {
    print("\(key) -> \(value)") 
  }
}
```

Output of print `value`:

```
value 0
value 0
value 1
value 0
value 0
value 1
value 0
value 0
value 1
value 0
value 0
value 0
value 0
value 0
value 1
value 0
value 1
value 1
value 0
value 0
```

Output of `print(answerDict)`

```
["correct_2": 1, "correct_5": 0, "correct_4": 1, "correct_3": 0, "correct_1": 0]
```

Output of `print("\(key) -> \(value)")`

```
correct_2 -> 1
correct_5 -> 0
correct_4 -> 1
correct_3 -> 0
correct_1 -> 0
```

Please note that print outputs have been shortened for readability.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the count of occurrences of `value` `1`

I get errors as value of type `Any` can't be compared to `int` `1`,
casting caused crash,
can't use for loop to check for value 1 to do `totalCountValOne += 1`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have a `[String: Any]` in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper because 'mainData' is of type 'JSON'

Comment: This addresses parsing an Any value to an Int: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091989/how-to-convert-any-to-int-in-swift

Comment: So why not use Codable if this is json?

Comment: Perhaps you can leverage on a swift `CountedSet` data structure in first instance, avoiding those nested for-in loops resulting in a quadratic time complexity algorithm. That is if your decoded JSON data could conform to `Hashable` protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the occurrences of value 1 from answerDict

Try this:

If the value is Int

```
 print(answerDict.filter({$0.value as? Int == 1 }).count)
```

If the value is String

```
print(answerDict.filter({$0.value as? String == "1" }).count)
```

Comment: Tried: returns 0

Comment: Can you print the answerDict and provide the values, so I can try and provide a solution

Comment: It works fine for me, I tried this -
 let dict : [String: Any] = ["correct_2": 1, "correct_5": 0, "correct_4": 1, "correct_3": 0, "correct_1": 0]
print(dict.filter({$0.value as? Int == 1 }).count)
And the output is 2.

Comment: Updated the answer for the case if the value is String type